# Android room migration add a list of enums

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm saving

```
data class Settings(
    val foo: Int
)
```

into my room database version 1.

Now I need to extend `Settings` to

```
data class Settings(
    val foo: Int,
    val bar: ArrayList<Baz>
)
```

where

```
enum class Baz {
    A, B, C
}
```

so I need to do a migration to version 2.

I have type converters for `bar`. I'm currently trying something like

```
val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE settings ADD COLUMN bar TEXT")
    }
}
```

but this gives me an `IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle Settings...` error.

And I'm stuck. So please help! How do I get that migration working??

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was my lack of SQLite skills that was in the way.

First of all, I needed to set a default value since my `bar`wasn't allowed to be `null`. Second, `ALTER TABLE` is crazy limited and didn't allow me to set a default value in one line.

I ended up doing

```
val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE settings_new (foo INTEGER NOT NULL, bar TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(foo))")
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO settings_new (foo, bar) SELECT foo, '[]' AS bar FROM settings")
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE settings")
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE settings_new RENAME TO settings")
    }
}
```

In other words

1. Create a new temporary table (`settings_new`)
2. Move old values into the new one. Notice that we set bar as an empty array as default.
3. Drop the original (`settings`) table
4. Rename the temporary to the old name (i.e. `settings_new` --> `settings`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change settings  table name Settings and you pass only setting..

```
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Settings ADD COLUMN bar TEXT")
```

after add..

```
database =  Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
    UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
    .build();
```

refer this ..
[Room database migration if only new table is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399852/room-database-migration-if-only-new-table-is-added?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks but this is the same thing. Room understands that it is `Settings` I want to alter, as shown in the error message.